# Who was the first to posit something akin to the falsifiability principle?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science

Peirce in  CP 5.199 writes something very similar to falsifiability principle namely the following:

> ...But these logicians refuse to admit that we can ever have a right to
> conclude definitely that a hypothesis is exactly true, that is that it
> should be able to sustain experimental tests in endless series; for,
> they urge, no hypothesis can be subjected to an endless series of
> tests. They are willing we should say that a theory is true, because,
> all our ideas being more or less vague and approximate, what we mean
> by saying that a theory is true can only be that it is very near true.
> But they will not allow us to say that anything put forth as an
> anticipation of experience should assert exactitude, because
> exactitude in experience would imply experiences in endless series,
> which is impossible

This sounds like the the main ingredient of the falsifiability of Popper since it can be naturally and trivially extended to it.
Who was the first person to write something close in meaning to the above quote?

Comment: There is nothing close to the falsifiability principle in this quote. Just because one criticizes naive induction does not mean they offer falsificationism as the alternative. And the demarcation problem to which it was an answer was not even current in the 19th century. There is a better case for Peirce anticipating falsificationism from his epistemological anti-foundationalism, replacing science of induction and/or "first principles" by guess-and-test. But see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/whewell/#SciInd) on the anachronism of reading e.g. Whewell as a "Popperian".

Comment: @Conifold  Ithought that since Peirce is saying that no hypothesis can be ever be proven  completely true  it's implied that it can only be proven false by new evidence(combined with verificationism).Do you know who was the first to say something similar as the quote by Peirce?

Comment: This sort of [criticism of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction) is often associated with Hume, but can be traced as far back as Pyrrho. But it is no falsificationism, not even "implied". Casting modern stereotypes as "trivial extensions" and projecting them into the past is not a good idea.

Comment: That's pretty judgmental, but if that's what you think why read his views into others? A major shift, which went against the grain of a venerable tradition from Aristotle to Kant, was away from viewing science as being after first principles, whose certainty must be justified and the rest built upon them. Peirce spelled out that both certainty and top-down justification were dispensable because scientific claims are subject to perpetual correction through testing, see e.g. CP 1.34. But verification vs falsification is not a distinction that exercised him or others at the time.

Comment: And like Whewell, he did not share Popper's (and positivists' btw) idea that hypothesis generation was an irrational affair best left to psychology. But Popper did articulate and popularize an aspirational ideal that a fraction of scientists still see themselves in. Being simplistic is probably what let it become a digestible pop-culture item that neither Peirce, nor positivists, nor Quine could produce through nuance and technicality.